# Convergence of Series with Factorial

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We have the sequence $$a_n=\frac{(2n)!^2}{16^n\cdot n!^4}$$
I am trying to prove this converges to 0, which is relatively easy using [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) (which I don't want to use). I have tried a myriad of things so far, what I think is the closest thing I have to a solution is rewriting it as a power series: $$a_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(k+n)^2}{16k^2}$$
From here we can see that for all $k$ greater than $k_0=\frac{1}{3}n$ the terms of the power series are smaller than 1, but I don"t know if this is enough to prove anything. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The equivalent of $\sqrt{a_n}$ as $n\to\infty$ is a classic application of [Wallis integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals). (it's a way to prove Stirling)

Comment: By the way, you haven't written a power series—it's a finite product.

Comment: @GregMartin but isn't it a power series for $\lim_{n\to\infty}$?

Comment: In the title you're asking about a series but in the main text it's about a sequence. Which is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\small 0<a_n=\left(\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}\right)^2<\frac12\cdot\frac34\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2n}\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac45\cdots\frac{2n}{2n+1}=\frac1{2n+1}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.$$