# How to bound $\binom{2n-1}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I am trying to prove that the following series is convergent :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!}{(2^{n} n!)^{2}}$$

If the numerator is $(2n)!$ then it is easily done by CT with $\frac{1}{2n+1}$; however for this case I can't find out how to bound it. (LCT does not work since the limit converges to $1$.)

I have found an upper bound for the sequence but it is no use since it is similar with $\frac{1}{n}$ which diverges. Can anyone help?

EDIT : I think the following question would be an answer since $\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2^{n} n!)^{2}} \le \frac{1}{2n\sqrt{3n+1}}$ and the $p$ series test.

[Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260778/prove-frac12-cdot-frac34-cdot-frac56-cdot-cdot-frac2n-12n-le-fra?noredirect=1)

Comment: Just notice that the sum is smaller than the case when the numerator is $\left(2n\right)!$ and then complete the proof with what you said, also what you are summing is not exactly $2^{-2n}\binom{2n-1}{n}$, is $2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{2n}$

Comment: I suggest formulas for [OEIS sequence A001700](https://oeis.org/A001700).

Comment: You can use Stirling’s approximation or Raabe’s convergence test for example.

Answer (score 2):

This is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{2n}$ with $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{(2^n n!)^2}\asymp\frac1{\sqrt{n\pi}}$ ([well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Asymptotic_growth); the weaker $a_n=O(n^{-1/2})$ is shown in *a lot of posts* here on MSE, including the one you mention, and even [my own](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4586729)). Moreover, it's easy to evaluate the given sum in closed form, using $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n=(1-z)^{-1/2}$: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{2n}=\int_0^1\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-1\right)\frac{dx}{x}=-\log\left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\Bigg|_0^1=\log2.$$